# Reading values from facebook batchrequest

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to read likes of all app using friends of Facebook. For that, I used graph API to get the ID and then batch request to get the likes.

But I am not able to iterate values properly in batchrequest. I'll explain it below.

I'm using the below code to get the ID of app using friends and storing in arraylist. I am calling `doBatchRequest` at the end which contains facebook batchrequest.

```
new Request(session,"/me/friends",null,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
   @Override
   public void onCompleted(Response response) {
      FBAnalysis_List = new ArrayList<FBAnalysisObj>();
      try {
         GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
         JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
         if(graphObject!=null){
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
               fbAnalysisObj_ref = new FBAnalysisObj();
               fbAnalysisObj_ref.setName(String.valueOf(object.get("name")));
               fbAnalysisObj_ref.setId(String.valueOf(object.get("id")));
               FBAnalysis_List.add(fbAnalysisObj_ref);
            }
            doBatchRequest();   
         }
      } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
   }
}).executeAsync();
```

In doBatchRequest:

```
Iterator fBAnalysis_List_itr = FBAnalysis_List.iterator();
while (fBAnalysis_List_itr.hasNext()) {
   fbAnalysisObj_ref = (FBAnalysisObj) fBAnalysis_List_itr.next();
   requestBatch.add(new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"/"+fbAnalysisObj_ref.getId()+"/likes",null, null,new Request.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
         JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
         try {
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            Log.d(TAG, "array count "+array.length());
            likes_count=array.length();
            Log.d(TAG, "likes_count "+likes_count);
            fbAnalysisObj_ref.setLikes(String.valueOf(likes_count));
            Log.d(TAG, "fbAnalysisObj_ref.getLikes() "+fbAnalysisObj_ref.getLikes());
            Log.d(TAG, "fbAnalysisObj_ref.getName() "+fbAnalysisObj_ref.getName());
            FB_obj_iteration_count++;
         } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }));
}
requestBatch.executeAsync();
```

The problem here is, in the `while` iteration I am getting the last facebook ID in the list instead of all of the IDs.

i.e. before calling the `requestBatch.add`, I am getting the log with all id's in the list

```
In while id is 678081895623440
In while id is 1380238265604356
```

But after `requestBatch.add`, I am getting last facebook ID in the last.

```
array count 20
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getLikes() 7
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getName() Demo Imp
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getId() 1380238265604356
array count 0
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getLikes() 7
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getName() Demo Imp
fbAnalysisObj_ref.getId() 1380238265604356
```

Is there anything wrong in the iteration? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That will only work with Graph API v1.0, after that the `friends_*` permissions have been removed. This makes it impossible to get friends data. v1.0 is only available until April 30th 2015.

If you're using v1.0, a much easier way would be to query

```
/me/friends?fields=id,likes.limit(500)
```

Comment: if i'm using like this, I'm getting error message as "{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}
"

Comment: Well, read the error message. You're using an expired access token.

Comment: Just replace `/me/friends` with `/me/friends?fields=id,likes.limit(500)`. The error message is about an expired acces token.